# How to collapse nodes using python

Tags: python

I have the following code, however there seems to be an error within it somewhere. I get output (a) but require output (b) - see below. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? All files are tab-delimited.

Code:

```
import sys

outfile_name = sys.argv[-1]
filename1 = sys.argv[-2]
filename2 = sys.argv[-3]
fileIn1 = open(filename1, "r")
fileIn2 = open(filename2, "r")
fileOut = open(outfile_name, "w")

dict = {}

a = open(filename1)
b = open(filename2)

for line in a:
words = line.split("\t")
if len(words) != 1:
    target = words[0]
    for word in words[1:]:
        dict[word] = target

for line in b:
words = line.split("\t")
if words[0] in dict.keys() and words[1] in dict.keys():
        fileOut.write(dict[words[0]] + "\t" + dict[words[1]] + "\n")
elif words[0] in dict.keys() and words[1] not in dict.keys():
        fileOut.write(dict[words[0]] + "\t" + words[1] + "\n")
elif words[0] not in dict.keys() and words[1] in dict.keys():
        fileOut.write(words[0] + "\t" + dict[words[1]] + "\n")
elif words[0] not in dict.keys() and words[1] not in dict.keys():
        fileOut.write(words[0] + "\t" + words[1] + "\n")


fileOut.close()
```

filename1:

```
Area_1 Area_2
A   B
A   C
A   D
D   B
D   C
L   B
L   C
L   A
D   L
K   A
K   B
K   C
K   D
K   L
D   P
D   R
L   P
L   R
K   P
K   R
A   H
D   H
L   H
K   H
B   P
B   R
R   P
A   I
D   I
I   L
I   K
C   H
I   H
C   H
J   K
J   X
J   Y
J   Z
K   X
K   Y
Y   Z
K   Z
X   Y
X   Z
M   G
N   T
O   S
S   Q
```

filename2:

```
Incident_00000001       A       D       L       K
Incident_00000002       B       P       R
Incident_00000003       C       F       W
Incident_00000004       J       I
M
N
O
Incident_00000005       Q       S
X
Y
Z
G
T
```

output (b) - undesired output that I am getting:

```
Area_1  Area_2

Incident_00000001   B

Incident_00000001   C

Incident_00000001   D

Incident_00000001   B

Incident_00000001   C

Incident_00000001   B

Incident_00000001   C

Incident_00000001   A

Incident_00000001   L

K   A

K   B

K   C

K   D

K   L

Incident_00000001   P

Incident_00000001   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   P

Incident_00000001   Incident_00000002
K   P

K   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   H

Incident_00000001   H

Incident_00000001   H

K   H

Incident_00000002   P

Incident_00000002   Incident_00000002
R   P

Incident_00000001   Incident_00000003
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000003
I   L

I   Incident_00000004
Incident_00000003   H

I   H

Incident_00000003   H

Incident_00000004   Incident_00000004
Incident_00000004   X

Incident_00000004   Y

Incident_00000004   Z

K   X

K   Y

Y   Z

K   Z

X   Y

X   Z

M   G

N   T

O   S

Incident_00000005   Incident_00000005
```

What I am looking to get (output (c)) is:

```
Area_1  Area_2
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000003
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000001
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000003
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000003
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000001
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000001
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000001
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000003
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000001
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000001
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   H
Incident_00000001   H
Incident_00000001   H
Incident_00000001   H
Incident_00000002   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000002   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000002   Incident_00000002
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000004
Incident_00000001   Incident_00000004
Incident_00000004   Incident_00000001
Incident_00000004   Incident_00000001
Incident_00000003   H
Incident_00000004   H
Incident_00000003   H
Incident_00000004   Incident_00000001
Incident_00000004   X
Incident_00000004   Y
Incident_00000004   Z
Incident_00000001   X
Incident_00000001   Y
Y   Z
Incident_00000001   Z
X   Y
X   Z
M   G
N   T
O   Incident_00000005
Incident_00000005   Incident_00000005
```

Comment: That second file is just terrible. Maybe you can provide column names so we have a better idea?

Comment: Your code shouldn't run, as `filename2` has rows that contain only one column, and your code for `filename2` expects at least two columns per row. Also, you have a syntax error in `for word in words[1-:]:`, where I think you meant to say `for word in words[1:]:`. Please recheck your post to ensure it is representative of what you actually have. I do actually understand the rest of your question, and can answer it as soon as you address these concerns

Comment: Hi inspectorG4dget, if a line in filename2 contains just one column I don't want to change the values in filename1, is this possible?

Comment: Hi FirebladeDan, filename2 is an output of a different program I have. If there is an "Incident_0000000X" at the beginning of the line all following letters represent the same incident. If there isn't an "Incident_0000000X" it means that the incident is a single occurrence and I would like to leave it as such. Thanks.

Comment: Can we assume that each letter of the alphabet appears no more than once in `filename2`?

Comment: Yes, that should be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

graph = {}
with open(filename2) as infile:
    for incident, *rest in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):
        if not rest: continue
        for node in rest:
            graph[node] = incident

with open('filename1') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    for source, dest in csv.reader(infile):
        if source in graph: source = graph[source]
        if dest in graph: dest = graph[dest]
        writer.writerow([source, dest])
```

Comment: I've only seen this now. Thank you so much for your help